# Finite generation of the image of the induced homomorphism on homotopy groups of infinite loops spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, homology

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a map of infinite loop spaces such that image of homology groups $H_i(X,\mathbb{Z})$ for $i\geq 1$ under $f_*$ are finitely generated. Does this imply that the image of homotopy groups under $f_*$ are also finitely generated?
Few tips that might be helpful:

This is true for $\pi_1$ since it is Abelian.

This is true rationally.

In my case $X\rightarrow Y$ happens to be a covering space map too. So feel free to use that fact.

There is a counter-example if I replace the infinite loop space by $H$-space and you can see it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3229869).

Comment: I think you can get something in these lines, maybe the exact statement, applying Serre’s theory of class of Abelian groups to the Whitehead theorem. Look at Mosher and Tangora’s book.

Comment: If this is true it cannot be implies by just Serre mod $C$ and Whitehead theorem. Because there is a counter example for the case of $H$-spaces. It somehow needs  to use the fact the map is an infinite loop space map.